# R multiples strings aggregate

Tags: r, string, aggregate

I'm trying to aggregate multiple rows by column in a data frame. I succed to use aggregate for one column \o/ but I don't understand how to use it for several columns. I let you an exemple of my data:

```
Gene_Title                                                  ID_Affymetrix   GB_Acc.x    Gene_Symbol.x   Entrez  ID_Agl  GB_Acc.y    Gene_Symbol.y   Unigene     Ensembl              Chr_location
trafficking protein particle complex 4                      1429632_at      AK005276    Trappc4         60409   10239   NM_021789   Trappc4         Mm.29814    ENSMUST00000170082   chr9:44211918-44211859
aldo-keto reductase family 1, member B3 (aldose reductase)  1437133_x_at    AV127085    Akr1b3          11677   22      NM_009658   Akr1b3          Mm.451      ENSMUST00000166583   chr6:34253982-34253930
sodium channel, voltage-gated, type I, alpha                1450120_at      AV336781    Scn1a           20265   58      NM_018733   Scn1a           Mm.439704   ENSMUST00000094951   chr2:66173557-66173498
sodium channel, voltage-gated, type I, alpha                1450121_at      AV336781    Scn1a           20265   58      NM_018733   Scn1a           Mm.439704   ENSMUST00000094951   chr2:66173557-66173498
aldo-keto reductase family 1, member B3 (aldose reductase)  1456590_x_at    BB469763    Akr1b3          11677   22      NM_009658   Akr1b3          Mm.451      ENSMUST00000166583   chr6:34253982-34253930
dolichol-phosphate (beta-D) mannosyltransferase 2           1415675_at      BC008256    Dpm2            13481   33459   NM_010073   Dpm2            Mm.22001    ENSMUST00000150419   chr2:32428766-32428825
proline rich 13                                             1423686_a_at    BC016234    Prr13           66151   4       NM_025385   Prr13           Mm.393955   ENSMUST00000164688  chr15:102291090-102291149
transmembrane protein 2                                     1424711_at      BC019745    Tmem2           83921   23      NM_031997   Tmem2           Mm.329776   ENSMUST00000096194   chr19:21930192-21930251
transmembrane protein 2                                     1451458_at      BC019745    Tmem2           83921   23      NM_031997   Tmem2           Mm.329776   ENSMUST00000096194   chr19:21930192-21930251
lipase, endothelial                                         1450188_s_at    BC020991    Lipg            16891   52      NM_010720   Lipg            Mm.299647   ENSMUST00000066532  chr18:75099688-75099629
lipase, endothelial                                         1421261_at      BC020991    Lipg            16891   52      NM_010720   Lipg            Mm.299647   ENSMUST00000066532   chr18:75099688-75099629
lipase, endothelial                                         1421262_at      BC020991    Lipg            16891   52      NM_010720   Lipg            Mm.299647   ENSMUST00000066532   chr18:75099688-75099629
coatomer protein complex, subunit gamma                     1415670_at      BC024686    Copg            54161   25829   NM_017477   Copg            Mm.258785   ENSMUST00000113607   chr6:87862890-87862949
coatomer protein complex, subunit gamma                     1416017_at      BC024686    Copg            54161   25829   NM_017477   Copg            Mm.258785   ENSMUST00000113607   chr6:87862890-87862949
leucine rich repeat containing 1                            1452411_at      BG966295    Lrrc1           214345  29      NM_172528   Lrrc1           Mm.28534    ENSMUST00000049755   chr9:77278998-77278939
aldo-keto reductase family 1, member B3 (aldose reductase)  1448319_at      NM_009658   Akr1b3          11677   22      NM_009658   Akr1b3          Mm.451      ENSMUST00000166583   chr6:34253982-34253930
ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V0 subunit D1            1415671_at      NM_013477   Atp6v0d1        11972   11826   NM_013477   Atp6v0d1        Mm.17708    ENSMUST00000013304   chr8:108048837-108048778
golgi autoantigen, golgin subfamily a, 7                    1415672_at      NM_020585   Golga7          57437   54944   NM_020585   Golga7          Mm.196269   ENSMUST00000121783   chr8:24351978-24351919
trafficking protein particle complex 4                      1415674_a_at    NM_021789   Trappc4         60409   10239   NM_021789   Trappc4         Mm.29814    ENSMUST00000170082   chr9:44211918-44211859  
phosphoserine phosphatase                                   1415673_at      NM_133900   Psph            100678  57142   NM_133900   Psph            Mm.271784   ENSMUST00000031399   chr5:130271500-130271441
```

Some gene_title (and gene_symbol) are represented several times but with different ID(Affymetrix or Agilent), or with different GB_Acc. In general I want to have only one line per gene and in Ids or GB_Acc or other columns the different values: 
Here my data with Id affymetrix:

```
>f=function(x){return(paste(x,collapse=","))}   
>tab4=aggregate(ID_Affymetrix ~ GB_Acc.x+ Gene_Title+GB_Acc.y+Gene_Symbol.x+Entrez+Unigene+Ensembl+Chr_location+ID_Agl,data=tab3,f)

GB_Acc.x    Gene_Title                                                  GB_Acc.y    Gene_Symbol.x   Entrez  Unigene     Ensembl             Chr_location                ID_Agl  ID_Affymetrix
BC016234    proline rich 13                                             NM_025385   Prr13           66151   Mm.393955   ENSMUST00000164688  chr15:102291090-102291149   4       1423686_a_at
AV127085    aldo-keto reductase family 1, member B3 (aldose reductase)  NM_009658   Akr1b3          11677   Mm.451      ENSMUST00000166583  chr6:34253982-34253930      22      1437133_x_at
BB469763    aldo-keto reductase family 1, member B3 (aldose reductase)  NM_009658   Akr1b3          11677   Mm.451      ENSMUST00000166583  chr6:34253982-34253930      22      1456590_x_at
NM_009658   aldo-keto reductase family 1, member B3 (aldose reductase)  NM_009658   Akr1b3          11677   Mm.451      ENSMUST00000166583  chr6:34253982-34253930      22      1448319_at
BC019745    transmembrane protein 2                                     NM_031997   Tmem2           83921   Mm.329776   ENSMUST00000096194  chr19:21930192-21930251     23      1424711_at,1451458_at
BG966295    leucine rich repeat containing 1                            NM_172528   Lrrc1           214345  Mm.28534    ENSMUST00000049755  chr9:77278998-77278939      29      1452411_at
BC020991    lipase, endothelial                                         NM_010720   Lipg            16891   Mm.299647   ENSMUST00000066532  chr18:75099688-75099629     52      1450188_s_at,1421261_at,1421262_at
AV336781    sodium channel, voltage-gated, type I, alpha                NM_018733   Scn1a           20265   Mm.439704   ENSMUST00000094951  chr2:66173557-66173498      58      1450120_at,1450121_at
AK005276    trafficking protein particle complex 4                      NM_021789   Trappc4         60409   Mm.29814    ENSMUST00000170082  chr9:44211918-44211859      10239   1429632_at
NM_021789   trafficking protein particle complex 4                      NM_021789   Trappc4         60409   Mm.29814    ENSMUST00000170082  chr9:44211918-44211859      10239   1415674_a_at
NM_013477   ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V0 subunit D1            NM_013477   Atp6v0d1        11972   Mm.17708    ENSMUST00000013304  chr8:108048837-108048778    11826   1415671_at
BC024686    coatomer protein complex, subunit gamma                     NM_017477   Copg            54161   Mm.258785   ENSMUST00000113607  chr6:87862890-87862949      25829   1415670_at,1416017_at
BC008256    dolichol-phosphate (beta-D) mannosyltransferase 2           NM_010073   Dpm2            13481   Mm.22001    ENSMUST00000150419  chr2:32428766-32428825      33459   1415675_at
NM_020585   golgi autoantigen, golgin subfamily a, 7                    NM_020585   Golga7          57437   Mm.196269   ENSMUST00000121783  chr8:24351978-24351919      54944   1415672_at
NM_133900   phosphoserine phosphatase                                   NM_133900   Psph            100678  Mm.271784   ENSMUST00000031399  chr5:130271500-130271441    57142   1415673_at
```

As you can see, for Tmem2, Copg,Lipg and Scn1a I now have several ID_Affymetrix in the same row. For this genes the only difference was on this column. But for Akr1b3 and Trappc4 there was also some difference in th GB_acc.x column.

So in a general way I would like to make an aggregate for each columns (except Gene_Title and Gene_Symbol which normally are always the same for a given gene) and finally have for exemple:

```
Gene_Tile                  Gene_Symbol  GB_Acc              ID_Affy                   ...
Traffickp Prot complex 4   Trapcc4      AK005276,NM_021789  1429632_at,1415674_a_at   ...
```

If anyone as any idea

Thanks!

EDIT:
this is the dput(head(mydata,20)). There's some errors at the end but I didn't know this function and his goal

```
structure(list(Gene_Title = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("aldo-keto reductase family 1, member B3 (aldose reductase)", 
"ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V0 subunit D1", "coatomer protein complex, subunit gamma", 
"dolichol-phosphate (beta-D) mannosyltransferase 2", "golgi autoantigen, golgin subfamily a, 7", 
"leucine rich repeat containing 1", "lipase, endothelial", "phosphoserine phosphatase", 
"proline rich 13", "sodium channel, voltage-gated, type I, alpha", 
"trafficking protein particle complex 4", "transmembrane protein 2"
), class = "factor"), ID_Affymetrix = structure(c(13L, 14L, 20L, 
2L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 19L, 17L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 15L, 16L, 5L, 
12L, 11L, 18L), .Label = c("1415670_at", "1415671_at", "1415672_at", 
"1415673_at", "1415674_a_at", "1415675_at", "1416017_at", "1421261_at", 
"1421262_at", "1423686_a_at", "1424711_at", "1429632_at", "1437133_x_at", 
"1448319_at", "1450120_at", "1450121_at", "1450188_s_at", "1451458_at", 
"1452411_at", "1456590_x_at"), class = "factor"), GB_Acc.x = structure(c(2L, 
11L, 4L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 13L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 15L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 14L, 1L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("AK005276", "AV127085", "AV336781", 
"BB469763", "BC008256", "BC016234", "BC019745", "BC020991", "BC024686", 
"BG966295", "NM_009658", "NM_013477", "NM_020585", "NM_021789", 
"NM_133900"), class = "factor"), Gene_Symbol.x = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 
12L, 12L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("Akr1b3", "Atp6v0d1", "Copg", 
"Dpm2", "Golga7", "Lipg", "Lrrc1", "Prr13", "Psph", "Scn1a", 
"Tmem2", "Trappc4"), class = "factor"), Entrez = c(11677L, 11677L, 
11677L, 11972L, 54161L, 54161L, 13481L, 57437L, 214345L, 16891L, 
16891L, 16891L, 100678L, 66151L, 20265L, 20265L, 60409L, 60409L, 
83921L, 83921L), ID_Agl = c(22L, 22L, 22L, 11826L, 25829L, 25829L, 
33459L, 54944L, 29L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 57142L, 4L, 58L, 58L, 10239L, 
10239L, 23L, 23L), GB_Acc.y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L
), .Label = c("NM_009658", "NM_010073", "NM_010720", "NM_013477", 
"NM_017477", "NM_018733", "NM_020585", "NM_021789", "NM_025385", 
"NM_031997", "NM_133900", "NM_172528"), class = "factor"), Gene_Symbol.y = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 
12L, 12L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("Akr1b3", "Atp6v0d1", "Copg", 
"Dpm2", "Golga7", "Lipg", "Lrrc1", "Prr13", "Psph", "Scn1a", 
"Tmem2", "Trappc4"), class = "factor"), Unigene = structure(c(12L, 
12L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
7L, 7L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("Mm.17708", "Mm.196269", "Mm.22001", 
"Mm.258785", "Mm.271784", "Mm.28534", "Mm.29814", "Mm.299647", 
"Mm.329776", "Mm.393955", "Mm.439704", "Mm.451"), class = "factor"), 
Ensembl = structure(c(11L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("ENSMUST00000013304", 
"ENSMUST00000031399", "ENSMUST00000049755", "ENSMUST00000066532", 
"ENSMUST00000094951", "ENSMUST00000096194", "ENSMUST00000113607", 
"ENSMUST00000121783", "ENSMUST00000150419", "ENSMUST00000164688", 
"ENSMUST00000166583", "ENSMUST00000170082"), class = "factor"), 
Chr_location = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 
12L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("chr15:102291090-102291149", 
"chr18:75099688-75099629", "chr19:21930192-21930251", "chr2:32428766-32428825", 
"chr2:66173557-66173498", "chr5:130271500-130271441", "chr6:34253982-34253930", 
"chr6:87862890-87862949", "chr8:108048837-108048778", "chr8:24351978-24351919", 
"chr9:44211918-44211859", "chr9:77278998-77278939"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Gene_Title", 
"ID_Affymetrix", "GB_Acc.x", "Gene_Symbol.x", "Entrez", "ID_Agl", 
"GB_Acc.y", "Gene_Symbol.y", "Unigene", "Ensembl", "Chr_location"
), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
structure(list(Gene_Title = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("aldo-keto reductase family 1, member B3 (aldose reductase)", 
"ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V0 subunit D1", "coatomer protein complex, subunit gamma", 
"dolichol-phosphate (beta-D) mannosyltransferase 2", "golgi autoantigen, golgin subfamily a, 7", 
"leucine rich repeat containing 1", "lipase, endothelial", "phosphoserine phosphatase", 
"proline rich 13", "sodium channel, voltage-gated, type I, alpha", 
"trafficking protein particle complex 4", "transmembrane protein 2"
), class = "factor"), ID_Affymetrix = structure(c(13L, 14L, 20L, 
2L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 19L, 17L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 15L, 16L, 5L, 
12L, 11L, 18L), .Label = c("1415670_at", "1415671_at", "1415672_at", 
"1415673_at", "1415674_a_at", "1415675_at", "1416017_at", "1421261_at", 
"1421262_at", "1423686_a_at", "1424711_at", "1429632_at", "1437133_x_at", 
"1448319_at", "1450120_at", "1450121_at", "1450188_s_at", "1451458_at", 
"1452411_at", "1456590_x_at"), class = "factor"), GB_Acc.x = structure(c(2L, 
11L, 4L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 13L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 15L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 14L, 1L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("AK005276", "AV127085", "AV336781", 
"BB469763", "BC008256", "BC016234", "BC019745", "BC020991", "BC024686", 
"BG966295", "NM_009658", "NM_013477", "NM_020585", "NM_021789", 
"NM_133900"), class = "factor"), Gene_Symbol.x = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 
12L, 12L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("Akr1b3", "Atp6v0d1", "Copg", 
"Dpm2", "Golga7", "Lipg", "Lrrc1", "Prr13", "Psph", "Scn1a", 
"Tmem2", "Trappc4"), class = "factor"), Entrez = c(11677L, 11677L, 
11677L, 11972L, 54161L, 54161L, 13481L, 57437L, 214345L, 16891L, 
16891L, 16891L, 100678L, 66151L, 20265L, 20265L, 60409L, 60409L, 
83921L, 83921L), ID_Agl = c(22L, 22L, 22L, 11826L, 25829L, 25829L, 
33459L, 54944L, 29L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 57142L, 4L, 58L, 58L, 10239L, 
10239L, 23L, 23L), GB_Acc.y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L
), .Label = c("NM_009658", "NM_010073", "NM_010720", "NM_013477", 
"NM_017477", "NM_018733", "NM_020585", "NM_021789", "NM_025385", 
"NM_031997", "NM_133900", "NM_172528"), class = "factor"), Gene_Symbol.y = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 
12L, 12L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("Akr1b3", "Atp6v0d1", "Copg", 
"Dpm2", "Golga7", "Lipg", "Lrrc1", "Prr13", "Psph", "Scn1a", 
"Tmem2", "Trappc4"), class = "factor"), Unigene = structure(c(12L, 
12L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
7L, 7L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("Mm.17708", "Mm.196269", "Mm.22001", 
"Mm.258785", "Mm.271784", "Mm.28534", "Mm.29814", "Mm.299647", 
"Mm.329776", "Mm.393955", "Mm.439704", "Mm.451"), class = "factor"), 
Ensembl = structure(c(11L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("ENSMUST00000013304", 
"ENSMUST00000031399", "ENSMUST00000049755", "ENSMUST00000066532", 
"ENSMUST00000094951", "ENSMUST00000096194", "ENSMUST00000113607", 
"ENSMUST00000121783", "ENSMUST00000150419", "ENSMUST00000164688", 
"ENSMUST00000166583", "ENSMUST00000170082"), class = "factor"), 
Chr_location = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 
12L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("chr15:102291090-102291149", 
"chr18:75099688-75099629", "chr19:21930192-21930251", "chr2:32428766-32428825", 
"chr2:66173557-66173498", "chr5:130271500-130271441", "chr6:34253982-34253930", 
"chr6:87862890-87862949", "chr8:108048837-108048778", "chr8:24351978-24351919", 
"chr9:44211918-44211859", "chr9:77278998-77278939"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Gene_Title", 
"ID_Affymetrix", "GB_Acc.x", "Gene_Symbol.x", "Entrez", "ID_Agl", 
"GB_Acc.y", "Gene_Symbol.y", "Unigene", "Ensembl", "Chr_location"
), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
Erreur dans `?`(dput(head(tab3, 20)), dput(head(tab3, 20))) : 
c("pas de documentation de type ‘c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12)’ et de thème ‘dput(head(tab3, 20))’ (ou erreur de traitement de l'aide)", "pas de documentation de type ‘c(13, 14, 20, 2, 1, 7, 6, 3, 19, 17, 8, 9, 4, 10, 15, 16, 5, 12, 11, 18)’ et de thème ‘dput(head(tab3, 20))’ (ou erreur de traitement de l'aide)", "pas de documentation de type ‘c(2, 11, 4, 12, 9, 9, 5, 13, 10, 8, 8, 8, 15, 6, 3, 3, 14, 1, 7, 7)’ et de thème ‘dput(head(tab3, 20))’ (ou erreur de traitement de l'aide)", 
"pas de documentation de type ‘c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 9, 8, 10, 10, 12, 12, 11, 11)’ et de thème ‘dput(head(tab3, 20))’ (ou erreur de traitement de l'aide)", "pas de documentation de type ‘c(11677, 11677, 11677, 11972, 54161, 54161, 13481, 57437, 214345, 16891, 16891, 16891, 100678, 66151, 20265, 20265, 60409, 60409, 83921, 83921)’ et de thème ‘dput(head(tab3, 20))’ (ou erreur de traitement de l'a
```

Comment: I don't understand : what is the column(s) you want to group your data by ?

Comment: I have some difficulties to clearly explain: the fact is sometimes I have genes with same gene_title and gene_symbol but different description(different GB_acc or different ID_affymetrix, or maybe different unigene access). I don't want duplicated lines and I want to group (for exemple again) row 1 column ID_Aff and row 5 column ID_Affy when row 1 column gene_title == row 5 column gene_title. I want to repeat this for each column in my table except for gene_title and gene_symbol column. I hope it's a little bit clearer. Maybe aggregate is not the correct function to use in this case.

Comment: Can you provide your data as the output of `dput(head(yourdata,20))`? I cannot easily copy and paste it. And please edit your question, dont put this in comments.

Comment: @Maryvonne So you want to group your data by `gene_title` and `gene_symbol` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
library(dplyr)

dfcollapsed <- df %>%               # replace df with the name of your data frame
   group_by(Gene_Title, Gene_Symbol) %>% 
   summarise_each(funs(paste(., collapse = ",")))
```

I didn't test it with your data though, because I couldn't copy and paste it into my session.

#### Update:

In your data you have two columns `Gene_Symbol.x` and `Gene_Symbol.y` which were probably created during a `merge`. I assume they have the same information, and hence you could adjust the code to:

```
dfcollapsed <- df %>%               # replace df with the name of your data frame
   group_by(Gene_Title, Gene_Symbol.x) %>% 
   summarise_each(funs(paste(., collapse = ",")), -Gene_Symbol.y)
```

Or, if you only want unique entries in each column (as in @juba's answer) you can write:

```
dfcollapsed <- df %>%               # replace df with the name of your data frame
   group_by(Gene_Title, Gene_Symbol.x) %>% 
   summarise_each(funs(paste(unique(.), collapse = ",")), -Gene_Symbol.y)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, It works great! I will have to learn about this package ^^

Comment: @Maryvonne very welcome. FYI, if someone answers your question satisfactorily, you can accept the question by clicking the green check mark next to the question indicating that this question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following with `aggregate` :

```
f <- function(v) {paste(unique(v), collapse=", ")}
aggregate(tab3, list(tab3$Gene_Title, tab3$Gene_Symbol.x), f)
```

Comment: +1 for a base R approach, always a good comparison to non-base solutions

Comment: Well, if I didn't forget about `summarise_each()`, I would have provided a `dplyr` solution too :-)

Comment: Thanks, your solution works but give me a new data.frame with 2 new columns, Group.1 and Group.2, corresponding to Gene_Title and Gene_Symbol.x (in the new data.frame I always have Gene_Title and Gene_Symbol)